# Displaying Event Location and Online Registration through CiviCRM Entity

Tags: civievent

We are working on a Drupal 8 site with CiviCRM installed. Through CiviCRM entity, we are able to display some of the event information. However, three important things are not displayed, Event Location, Online Registration, and Profiles.

According to this blog post, they can be displayed in Drupal 7. So why not on Drupal 8? Is it doable at all? Any ideas and advice would be really appreciated:

https://skvare.com/blog/civicrm-entity-and-drupal-integration-whats-new-whats-next

Comment: If you want to create an Event Registration -> check out Webform CiviCRM module. Also -> do update to Drupal 9 (Drupal 8 is EOL today)